# CLI with nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, npm

I'm developing a CLI in node that will be published to NPM.
Since it's a CLI application, I want it to be included in the path once it's installed, so it's not require to type "node my-app.js" to run it. I want it to run with only "my-app".

In the package.json, I'm including:

```
"bin": { 
    "my-all" : "./my-app.js" 
 },
```

But this makes fail the installation via NPM with this error

**Error: ENOENT, chmod '/home/user1/node_modules/my-app/my-app'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on some kind of unix (linux, osx), put this line at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Also make sure you set the file to executable (`chmod a+x my-all`).

That should take care of the need to type `node my-app.js`, and enable you instead to just type `./my-app.js`.

As for the npm packaging stuff I am not sure why it fails, but I'm guessing it's an issue with the path or location of your my-app.js .

If an executable script is put anywhere in the PATH, then it will be run just like anything else. If you run `which npm`, you will see where the npm executable script is located. On my system, most node executable (or executable npm scripts) goes into /usr/local/bin. I'm assuming your `package.json` can be set to put it somewhere in the path. If you need to change the path, then modify your `.profile`, or alternatively your system path.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I've seen node apps installed with NPM running without the "./" and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: NPM itself is an example. it;s a nodejs app installed globally and you just need to type "npm" to run it. Tks