# CLI npm install not working

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

Can't get CLI npm to work:

```
Colins-MacBook-Pro:workshop colinlikethewind$ sudo npm install -g plugman
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/plugman
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/plugman

etc (ie: successful install)...

Colins-MacBook-Pro:workshop colinlikethewind$ plugman
-bash: plugman: command not found
```

Plugman is the example here used, but seems to be the case with all npm installs. Can anyone shed light onto this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLI with nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596420/cli-with-nodejs)